# How can I search in text and integer data types together optimally?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Here is my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
WHERE user_id = :user_id
  AND MATCH(subject, content) AGAINST(:entry)
```

See? I need an index for that integer `posts(user_id)`, also I've another separated full-text index on those two columns `posts(suject,content)`.

Anyway, how can I make one single index in such a situations to make the performance more optimal?

Comment: Basically, you can't since the first one is a B-TREE index, the second is a FULLTEXT.

Answer (score 1):

"Text" and "integer" is not the issue.  BTree and FULLTEXT is the issue.

But there is not much of a problem...  The Optimizer will always pick the FULLTEXT index (`MATCH...`) first.  If that returns a suitably small number of rows, then the further filtering by `user_id` will be not too costly.  If `user_id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `posts`, it will be even better.  (If this is WP, it can't be the PK.)

Possibly you want `AGAINST(:entry IN BOOLEAN MODE)`?

Comment: Ah I see.upvote, Just what happens if I add `IN BOOLEAN MODE` there? I thought I have to use it if I want make wildcard-searching available (by adding `*` in the end of it), Anyway, what's the benefit of using it?

Comment: @MartinAJ - Perhaps not a lot in your case.